# wrong number of values error when executing a stored procedure PL/SQL

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, plsql

I am trying to return a value from a procedure and i keep getting the error about wrong number of arguments but i am passing the correct number of arguments to this stored procedure i have written. Am i missing something here because i cannot find the error!

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE GETPLAYERDETAILS 
(
  PLAYERID IN NUMBER, 
  FORENAME IN VARCHAR2, 
  LASTNAME IN VARCHAR2, 
  theID OUT NUMBER
)  IS

 CURSOR player_cur IS
 SELECT ID from Player
 WHERE ID = PLAYERID OR NAME=FORENAME OR SURNAME = LASTNAME;

 player_rec player_cur%rowtype;

 BEGIN
  OPEN player_cur;
  FETCH player_cur into theID;
    if player_cur%notfound then
      return;
    end if;
   CLOSE player_cur;
END GETPLAYERDETAILS;
```

The error i get is:

```
Error starting at line : 1 in command -
EXEC GETPLAYERDETAILS(2, 'LIONEL', 'MESSI')
Error report -
ORA-06550: line 1, column 7:
PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'GETPLAYERDETAILS'
ORA-06550: line 1, column 7:
PL/SQL: Statement ignored
06550. 00000 -  "line %s, column %s:\n%s"
*Cause:    Usually a PL/SQL compilation error.
```

*Action:

Comment: You need 4 parameters for this procedure.

Comment: Even for the out parameter? My understanding is that you do not need to specify anything for the 'out parameter'.

If i try my procedure by right clicking on the procedure and clicking on RUN and pass in the parameters apart from the out parameter it works for me.

Comment: Right-click on what??? Your client app may be creating the proper pl/sql call signature and declaring an variable for the out parameter.  As @Egor says, yes, you need an variable in the host to hold the results.